# How to avoid ActiveCell in a UDF

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I have user-defined functions whose results depends on what cell they are in. One uses this line:

```
cel = Range("O" & ActiveCell.Row).value
```

and another includes:

```
CY = ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Cells(3).Value
```

I suspect that `ActiveCell` is causing problems (such as cells containing the UDFs spontaneously changing to the wrong answer).

I would think that relative references (like "R4C[0]") would work, but I'm not sure how to do that in code.

Is there another way to refer to Column "O" of the current row or Row 3 of the current column?

Comment: Why not pass those cells as arguments in the UDF,  without doing so you would have to make the UDF volatile or it will not re calculate when those referenced cells change. And making it volatile is not always the best option.

Comment: but to answer the question: `Application.Caller.Row`

Comment: `Application.Caller` or `ThisCell`

Comment: @ScottCraner There are multiple versions of the UDF. I want the user to be able to enter "=UDF1()" or "=UDF2()" in different cells as needed. If the referenced cell address is an argument, he'd have to enter "=UDF1($A4)" or "=UDF2($B5)", and trying to keep formulas like that straight was why he hired me in the first place!

Comment: Just remember to make them volatile then.  But remember that with volatility comes the need for Excel to run the code EVERY TIME a change is made anywhere on any versions of Excel which in the long run may cause overall slow down and the user experience will suffer.